# Not receiving attestations on Gnosis Node

Tags: nodes, gnosis, gnosis-chain, attestations

I have an Avado i7. I have been running two gnosis validators nodes for over one year. Starting around June 12-14 I stopped receiving attestations rewards. I followed the guidance of the Avado community and nothing has changed. They recommended I contact you for assistance. Things I have done that have not helped: I updated all the appropriate avado packages. I restarted all the packages. I did a disc clean up. Rebooted the system. Turned the avado device on and off. I opened ports 9000 and 9006. Currently the gnosis execution client (nethermind) is running and healthy. Avado teku gnosis beacon chain is in sync. When I go to gnosischa.in it shows my two validators are not active (last attestation 20 days ago) and are offline. I would appreciate any suggestions and guidance. I am not very technical with this stuff. Thank you,Mike

Answer (score 1):

Same hardware and no attestations for months now. The status of my nodes is acive exiting. (Kinda stange cause I didn't exit anything)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92698)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).